# All points y value undefined gnuplot

Tags: csv, time, graph, gnuplot

I'm having trouble with a time based graph on gnuplot. My graph plots the data of a CSV file from a noise sensor. My CSV file is written in the following format:

```
Time,Decibel
08:00:28,56.5
08:00:30,55.5
08:00:31,59.6
08:00:33,61.8
```

And so on.

My gnuplot script looks like this:

```
set datafile separator ","
set autoscale fix
set key outside right center
set xdata time
set timefmt '"%H:%M:%S"'
set xrange ['"08:00"':'"18:00"']
set terminal png
set output "/home/pi/Desktop/Codes/Graph/Picture/graph.png"
set title "Graph"

plot '/home/pi/Desktop/Codes/Graph/Values/2017-02-08.csv' using 1:2 with lines
```

What am I doing wrong? And is it possible to set the X to be every hour between 08:00 to 18:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that seems to be caused by the double quotes in:

```
set timefmt '"%H:%M:%S"'
set xrange ['"08:00"':'"18:00"']
```

try something like:

```
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["08:00:00":"18:00:00"]
```

As for the x-tics, one can set the beginning in the same notation as the xrange and then specify the step in seconds. For example to show a tic every 2 hours:

```
set xtics "08:00:00",2*3600
```

(Or, in fact, even `set xtics "08:00:00","02:00:00"` seems to work)